# Do I need to add miktex-qt5-bin or remove miktex-qt6-bin?

Tags: miktex-update

The MiKTeX console reports that I need to synchronize my user and admin updates.  But the way it wants to do this is to remove miktex-qt6-bin and keep only miktex-qt5-bin.  I tried that and it was disastrous.  I could no longer compile files or open the MiKTeX console at all.  I reinstalled MiKTeX, twice.

Both reinstallations worked but produced this warning

> The following issues were detected:   1: major issue:
> User/administrator updates are out-of-sync.

After the first reinstall I was able to compile documents.  But the console told me to request updates in User mode, and when I did that it crashed my MiKTeX again, as described.  Error messages said it needed qt6-bin.

After the second reinstall I refused the updates.  Now I cannot compile documents but I can open the console.  The package manager reports I currently have  miktex-qt5-bin packaged 3/8/2021 not installed, and it reports in red type that I have miktex-qt6-bin packaged 1/27/2024 installed today by Admin and also by User, and labelled as Obsolete.

UPDATE: I opened the Console in user mode, where the package listed miktex-qt6-bin as being installed today both by Admin and by User.  I said to remove it.  After that, the package manager listed it as installed only by Admin. I hoped that was good news.  But in fact this crashed my LaTeX installation as before, and I can no longer open the Console at all. I can reinstall for a third time today but I see no way to actually fix it.

Here is a screen shot of the current situation, after a third reinstall
[image]

What can I do to get it working?

Comment: do you really have miktex-qt6-bin installed by both? The user and admin?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is what the package manager reports, in red type, in user mode.  In Admin mode it reports qt-6 was installed only by Admin, and it use only normal black type

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I added a screen shot of the package manager,

Comment: Sorry I always install miktex in single user mode, so I can't tell you if that double installation is normal in multi user mode. I also never saw a red entry and don't know what it means. Open an issue at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues. (And as I wrote in your other questions: there are command line tools, so you should be able to install a package without opening the console.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Thanks.  I just got a github account.  But the lack of qt6 blocks most kinds of access to MiKTeX even from the command line except right after an install.  So collecting the requisite reports would require reinstalling yet again.  For now I'll have to switch my LaTeXing to Overleaf.